# How can I modify the background of a ListItem when it has been selected?

Tags: java, android, listview, listviewitem

I have a ListView with a bunch of ListItem's. When the user selects an item, I would like to change that ListItem's background to an image. How can I accomplish this?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    // how do I change the ListItem background here?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that in the adapter of your `ListView`. What you have to do is use the `setBackgroundResource` on the `View` that you are returning. Let me give you a brief example:

```
// lets suppose this is your adapter (which obviously has
//to be a custom one which extends from on of the main
//adapters BaseAdapter, CursorAdapter, ArrayAdapter, etc.)

// every adapter has a getView method that you will have to overwrite
// I guess you know what I'm talking about
public View getView( args blah blah ){
    View theView;
    // do stuff with the view

    // before returning, set the background
    theView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.the_custom_background);

    return theView;
}
```

Notice that I'm using `R.drawable.the_custom_background`, which means that you have to write a little XML selector. Don't worry, it's easier than it sounds. You create an XML file called `the_custom_background.xml` inside the `res/drawable` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/the_background_color" />
</selector>
```

Notice again, I'm using `@drawable/the_background_color`, so finally create another drawable in the `res/drawable` folder called `the_background_color`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
</shape>
```

I know it seems to be very messy, but this is the Android way. You could also try to modify the `View` inside the `setOnItemClickListener`, but I think that's undesirable and harder to implement.

Comment: By implementing this way, won't the background ALWAYS be `R.drawable.the_custom_background` ? I only want it to be `R.drawable.the_custom_background` when the ListItem is clicked. I'm not sure where that logic is, I assumed it would be inside of setOnItemClickListener...

Comment: OK... in that case, try `v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.the_custom_background);` inside the `onItemClick` method.

Comment: That works. But when the user clicks another listitem, I want the old listitem to revert back to the default background color

Comment: I have awarded you the answer, since I can change the background color. I have opened a new question regarding only changing the background color of the selected item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808175/listview-selector-problem-selection-does-not-expire