# ListView selector problem: Selection does not get removed

Tags: android, listview, selector, listviewitem

I have a ListView. When I click on a ListItem, I set the background of the ListItem (it's view) to another color:

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                    setupDetailView(position);
                    setupChartView(position);
                    setupARView(position);
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    quotesAdapter.isSelected = true;
                    //v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stocks_selector);
                }
            });
```

here is my adapter:

```
private class QuoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Quote> {

        private ArrayList<Quote> items;
        public boolean isSelected = false;

        public QuoteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Quote> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.mainrow, null);

                if(isSelected)
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                else
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparent_background);
            }
```

The problem is, if I select multiple rows, then multiple rows have a colored background. I only want the clicked item to have a colored background. So if I click on row 2, I want it to turn red, then if I click row 1, I want row 2 to go back to normal, and row 1 to turn red.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Put your list selector in your ListView

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/stocks_selector" />
```

your stocks_selector.xml should look something like

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    type="rectangle"

>
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/start_gradient"
        android:endColor="@color/end_gradient" 
        android:angle="270" />
/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Um, you don't need state list for that.  ListView will manage what's selected. Check out SDK drawables ( list....xml ) to see how to build selectors.

Comment: i did remove setBackround. I know that the ListView will manage what is selected, but I want to keep the selected state persistent until the user clicks another row. This is not recommended, but a behavior I am trying to create.

Comment: you can try following - add attribute isSelected for your item ( whatever you use in adapter)
onClick set this attribute to the item and remove it from previously marked item. In your getView set background based on the isSelected.

Comment: i created an isSelected member in my Adapter class, and set it in my onClick (see updated code). The background is not changing values.

Comment: you can sent the choice mood i.e listView.setChoiceMode(single/multiple);, setting it to single will solve your problem.